# setResult(int, intent) not working in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have tried many solutions now. However, I cannot get the compiler to approve setResult(int, intent) in my activity. I have started the activity with startActivityForResult.

Can you see the problem?

My code looks like this:

```
networkServiceMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //TODO: Implement the methods that should be executed on validation results

            PrinterData printerData = intent.getParcelableExtra(NetworkService.VALIDATE_PRINTER_RESULT);

            if(printerData != null)
            {
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra(VALIDATE_PRINTER_RESULT, printerData);

                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();

            }

            else
            {

            }
        }
    };
```

Android Studio gives this error:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`BroadcastReceiver` has its [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#setResult(int,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) method, which takes three parameters, not two, and you probably want to use `setResult` from the class `Activity`. Reference it like:

```
ActivityName.this.setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
```

if the `BroadcastReceiver` is declared inside an `Activity`

Comment: Thanks. This was just what I needed :) Also thanks for the code example :)

Answer (score 1):

`RESULT_OK` is constant of Activity class.

In Activity class you can access directly but in other classes you need to write class name (Activity) also.

Use `Activity.RESULT_OK` instead of `RESULT_OK`.